# How to put texts one on top of the other using JLabels?

Tags: java, jlabel, setbounds

I'm trying to make a list of texts that looks like this:

[image: image1]

I have this code:

```java
panelPunts = new JPanel();
panelPunts.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
biggerPanel.add(panelPunts, BorderLayout.EAST);

JLabel titol = new JLabel();
titol.setText("<html><h1><u> Points</u></h1></html>");
titol.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 50);
panelPunts.add(titol);

JLabel etnia1 = new JLabel();
etnia1.setText("Team A: 20");
etnia1.setBounds(0, 20, 200, 50);
panelPunts.add(etnia1);

JLabel etnia2 = new JLabel();
etnia2.setText("Team A: 10");
etnia2.setBounds(0, 40, 200, 50);
panelPunts.add(etnia2);
```

However, it looks like this:

[image: image2]

I've read that the second parameter in the `setBounds()` method is the Y position, however it doesn't change if I make it really high. Why doesn't it show properly?

Comment: `JPanel` by default use `FlowLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
JPanel panelPunts = new JPanel();

panelPunts.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
```

**`JPanel` by default uses `FlowLayout` and Never use `setBounds()`. Leave it for layout manager to set the position of the components**

For more sample code have a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#grid)

---

**Hint:** Just separate out the last two labels from the header. Add labels in another `JPanel`

Sample code : (using [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html))

```
    JPanel panelPunts = new JPanel();
    panelPunts.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    panelPunts.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

    JLabel titol = new JLabel();
    titol.setText("<html><h1><u> Points</u></h1></html>");
    panelPunts.add(titol, gc);

    gc.gridy = 1;
    JLabel etnia1 = new JLabel();
    etnia1.setText("Team A: 20");
    panelPunts.add(etnia1, gc);

    gc.gridy = 2;
    JLabel etnia2 = new JLabel();
    etnia2.setText("Team A: 10");
    panelPunts.add(etnia2, gc);
```

Comment: I've used this. Is there any way to not make it fill the entire JPanel?

Comment: yes use `GridBagLayout` where you have full control on the components.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use the `NullLayout`but any other LayoutManager (consider using the `GridLayout`). The FlowLayout which is standard layout when initializing a `JPanel` and which you are using is not suitable for this task. Also your `setBounds` method calls are only relevant when using NullLayout... which you should not. Also you could implement this with a `JList` and not multiple `JLabels`. Please consider changing your code with this information and if there a questions left update your answer.

Comment: Why don't use `FlowLayout`?

Comment: not for this task i meant. FlowLayout is just fine, just not suitable for this task.